# Implement Python tkinter zoom with turtle and single/double click

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw turtle in canvas and I am also trying to implement zoom in zoom out feature with single click and double click event. When I am not trying to implement tkinter the code works absolutely fine but when I am trying to perform zoom in zoom out feature, I am unable to execute it. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or help.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(master = root, width = 2700, height = 2500)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
mb = Menubutton(None, text='Mouse Clicks')
mb.pack()
t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

def parallel():
window= canvas

def zoomin(event):
    d = event.delta
    if d < 0:
       amt=0.9
    else:
       amt=1.1

    canvas.scale(ALL, 2700,2500 , amt,amt)
    mb.bind('<Button-1>', zoomin)

    def zoomout(event1, d1, amt1):
        d1 = event1.delta
        if d1 >0:
           amt1=1.1
        else:
           amt1=0.7
    canvas.scale(ALL, 2700,2500 , amt, amt)
    mb.bind('<Double-1>', zoomout)

    t.pu()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(70)
    t.rt(90)
    t.pd()
    t.width(8)
    t.color("LightGray")
    t.forward(1200)
    t.back(1200)
    t.pu()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(25)
    t.rt(90)
    t.pd()
    t.forward(1200)
    t.back(1200)

    t.pu()
    t.setposition(-85, 45)
    t.pd()
    t.forward(80)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(80)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(80)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(80)
    t.left(90)

    t.penup()                
    t.goto(-200, 160)       
    t.write("Class", True, align="center", font=('TimesNewRoman', 20, 'normal'))
    t.pendown()              
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-45, 150)
    t.write("1", True, align="center", font=('TimesNewRoman', 50, 'normal'))
    t.pendown()

    parallel() 
    t.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your program seems incomplete and structured incorrectly.  Below is my minimalist example of what I believe you're trying to do.  It draws a circle and then lets you use the mouse wheel to zoom it in and out:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen, ScrolledCanvas

def zoom(event):
    amount = 0.9 if event.delta < 0 else 1.1

    canvas.scale(tk.ALL, 0, 0, amount, amount)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = ScrolledCanvas(master=root, width=2000, height=2000)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-250)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(250)

canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', zoom)

screen.mainloop()
```

Note that certain turtle elements, like `dot()` and text generated with `write()` won't zoom, they'll remain fixed.  You'll need to read about the `.scale()` method, and go deeper into tkinter, to potentially work around this.  Or manually scale your fonts yourself.