# Zoom in and out function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to use zoom in, zoom out feature in python. I have previously tried to use the functionality to zoom in a line in turtle, canvas, etc. but nothing seem to work out, instead of zooming, the code is either increasing or decreasing the length of the line. I want to zoom in the line to add text on the line so that when a user zoom's in the line he/she can see the text. here is the code which I am trying to change.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root).pack()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
widget = Button(None, text='zoomin-out')
widget.pack()
canvas.create_line(175,175,225,225)

def zoomin(event):
    d = event.delta
    if d < 0:
       amt=0.9
    else:
       amt=1.1
    canvas.scale(ALL, 200,200, amt, amt)
widget.bind('<Button-1>', zoomin)
def zoomout(event):
    d = event.delta
    if d >0:
       amt=1.1
    else:
       amt=0.7
    canvas.scale(ALL, 200,200 , amt, amt)
widget.bind('<Double-1>', zoomout)
widget.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I believe that `event.delta` is only going to be meaningful for mouse-wheel events, not the click events you're binding here.  What were you expecting zooming a line to do, other than increasing or decreasing its length?  If you want the line to get thicker as you zoom in, you'd have to implement that yourself - `canvas.scale()` only adjusts coordinates, not any other of the canvas item properties.

Comment: When you zoom in on a line, it's naturally going to get longer.

Comment: I want to increase the width parallely. The increase in the width would allow the user to see the text which is placed in the circle upon clicking the zoom in button

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.  First, when you add both the `Button-1` and `Double-1` events to your Button widget, doing a double-click fires both events. They end up cancelling each other out, so only the single-click works as expected.

Second, as I pointed out in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069841/5771269), certain elements, like text, won't zoom, they'll remain fixed. You'll need to manually scale your fonts to simulate text zoom.

Below's a rework of your code along the above lines.  Instead of the problematic single and double click, I've changed it so that left and right clicks on the button cause the canvas to zoom in or out:

```
from tkinter import *

EXAMPLE_TEXT = "Left or Right click button to zoom in/out"
FONT_NAME = "Helvetica"
font_size = 12

def zoom(amount):
    global font_size

    canvas.scale(ALL, 200, 200, amount, amount)

    font_size *= amount
    canvas.itemconfigure(text_item, font=(FONT_NAME, int(font_size)))

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

text_item = canvas.create_text(200, 200, font=(FONT_NAME, font_size), text=EXAMPLE_TEXT)

canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 350, 350)

widget = Button(root, text='zoom in/out')
widget.pack()

widget.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: zoom(1.1))
widget.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e: zoom(0.7))

root.mainloop()
```

If you comment out the line that starts with `canvas.itemconfigure(...)`, you'll see that the circle continues to zoom in and out, but the text remains fixed size.

Comment: This code is only working for zoom in and also can you share how to increase the width of the circle when we click zoom in/ button

Comment: I want to the user to see the text I add on the circle, which is visible when the user zoom's in the circle.

Comment: @Siri, this code zooms in and out.  One is activated by the left mouse button, the other by the right mouse button.  If you don't have a right mouse button, try <ctrl> combined with the left mouse button.  Or, simply change the button bindings to something that works for you (just not single and double click on the same button!)